# PDFBox / Java: Printing to Paper:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a method that creates a PDF and saves it in the user's Documents folder (Windows, of course) with a file name of "temp.pdf". The last line in this method calls another method tht is intended to print the pdf file to paper. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

I'm using PDFBox to do the printing. The code isn't too involved, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Everything compiles just fine. This is a run time error. Can anyone see my mistake?  Thanks.

```
public static void printToPaper(String fPath) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("1");  //outputs correctly
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();   //error occurs right here
        System.out.println("2");  //never appears in output queue
        document = PDDocument.load(fPath);  
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService[] printService = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        printJob.setPrintService(printService[0]);
        document.silentPrint( printJob );
        document.close();
    }
```

Here is the full error log:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.(COSDocument.java:49)
>       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.(PDDocument.java:125)
>       at kidmath.PrintPDF.printToPaper(PrintPDF.java:12)
>       at kidmath.Print.printPaper(Print.java:83)
>       at kidmath.JDlgPrintSettings.btnPrintMouseClicked(JDlgPrintSettings.java:271)
>       at kidmath.JDlgPrintSettings.access$600(JDlgPrintSettings.java:10)
>       at kidmath.JDlgPrintSettings$7.mouseClicked(JDlgPrintSettings.java:170)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       ... 39 more

Comment: Could you post the full log. There must be a ClassNotFound exception down somewhere. Include all related jars, it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include commons logging to your class path and that should fix it. 
download link is here http://commons.apache.org/logging/

and the class that you are referring to is 
http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.0.3/docs/api/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html May be it's internally being referred from PDFBox API.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Java and don't know how to implement this suggestion. How do I add something to my class path?

Comment: Got it. Just needed the .jar file and include it with the libraries. The program still crashes, but now on the silent print line. I'll mark this as the solution and re-post if I can't get beyond that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the `PDDocument` class first before loading the file path.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
document = PDDocument.load(fPath);
```

That should fix it.