# pdfbox 3.0 Loader issue

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox 3.0 to load a PDF as follows (Eclipse IDE, java.runtime.version=17.0.4.1+1):

```
File pdfFile = new File("C:\\Users\SchroeT\\myPDF.pdf");
System.out.println("\n\nFile: " + pdfFile);
PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(pdfFile);
```

I added the following jar files to the Modulepath under "Libraries" in Eclipse:
fontbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
pdfbox-debugger-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
preflight-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
xmpbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar

The following output points to a “ClassNotFoundException”

Please help

Console output in Eclipse:

File: C:\Users\SchroeT\myPDF.pdf

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.pdfbox@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.(BaseParser.java:61)
at org.apache.pdfbox@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:343)
at org.apache.pdfbox@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:317)
at org.apache.pdfbox@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:277)
at org.apache.pdfbox@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:230)
at geoscene/geoscene.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:161)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 6 more

Comment: Have you also included the PDFBox dependencies into your eclipse project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDFBox / Java: Printing to Paper:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999593/pdfbox-java-printing-to-paperjava-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-comm)

Comment: I added the following jar files to the Modulepath under "Libraries" in Eclipse: fontbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, pdfbox-debugger-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, preflight-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, xmpbox-3.0.0-alpha3.jar

Comment: Adding these jar files to the classpath does not seem to fix the issue.  Instead, the pdfbox module can no longer be found

Comment: I found a solution:  I had to delete the module-info.java file.  After that, I ran into further issues (could not find PDAnnotationMarkup).  I removed all jar files mentioned above and only added the bigger pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I had to delete the module-info.java file. After that, I ran into further issues (could not find PDAnnotationMarkup). I removed all jar files mentioned above and only added the bigger pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar.